# Is there a way or a trick to set article translations to draft status in mass?

Tags: knowledge, translation

When you look at the published article translations on the Article Management tab, there is no way to mass edit them, there doesn't seem to be a way to set them to draft status unless you go one by one which it can become a time consuming task if you have hundreds of articles. Is anyone aware of some workaround to this( that doesn't include mass archiving the master version) or is just not possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The only actual solution is via API.

Comment: I have found a few issues when trying to get the Publishing Service Class methods to work in bulk. It would be great to have a few examples of their bulk usage in the documentation ;)